# "Opacity: 0;" errors out when precompiling assets on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Can't run `rake assets:precompile` on Heroku. I am getting

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  opacity:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 0;"
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)
(sass):24113
```

I don't understand how `opacity: 0;` is falsy.

Comment: based on the error `expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement`, it sounds like it hasn't been enclosed in { } properly, because it's thinking that `opacity` is a selector

Comment: try running `rake assets:precompile` on you local machine an see what line fails

Comment: @cocoa please post your comment as an answer, i will mark it as a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your selector hasn't been enclosed in { } properly, because it's thinking that `opacity` is a selector

Your css is probably something like this:

```
.className {
  /* styles here */
  opacity: 0;
```

Add a closing bracket and see if that fixes the problem

```
.className {
  /* styles here */
  opacity: 0;
}
```